# Facebook open graph video sharing with video suggestion and website link

Tags: facebook, video, facebook-opengraph

I am working on a video library project and I want to share the video on Facebook. My og meta tags are

```
<meta property="og:url"          content="https://test.mydomain.com/post/details/1" />
    <meta property="og:type"         content="video.movie" />
    <meta property="og:title"        content="Bibin And Blenda" />
    <meta property="og:description"  content=" #Videos  " />
    <meta property="og:image"        content="https://test.mydomain.com/data/event/500/2" />
    <meta property="fb:app_id"       content="1976568725906357"/>
    <meta property="og:site_name"       content="Big DayBookings"/>

        <meta property="og:video:url" content="https://test.mydomain.com/data/og_video/1">
    <meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="https://test.mydomain.com/data/og_video/1">
    <meta property="og:video:type" content="text/html">
    <meta property="og:video:width" content="1280">
    <meta property="og:video:height" content="720">
```

but when I click the play button in Facebook it wouldn't play the video, if I gave a video file URL instead of HTML 'og:video:url' it plays fine on Facebook but if it's an HTML it gives an error 'video format or mime type not supported', but I want it plays like a vimeo video shared on Facebook with all the like share button and got to website option.

And 'og:video:url' html page

```
<html class="gr__player_vimeo_com" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
        <title>YETI Presents: Carter Andrews from Talweg Creative on Vimeo</title>
    </head>
    <body data-gr-c-s-loaded="true" class="showfocus">
        <div id="player" class="player player-aa721499-4e81-40a5-9e22-e7c2f7860db8 js-player-fullscreen with-fullscreen with-sticky-custom-logo">
            <div class="player-inner">
                <div class="video-wrapper">
                    <div class="video" data-thumb="https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/645868523.jpg?mw=1400&amp;mh=688" data-thumb-width="1400" style="background-image: none;">
                        <div class="telecine">
                            <video preload="" src="https://test.mydomain.com/data/event_video/full/1"></video>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Currently you can't add custom HTML5 video player controls. Either you give FB the direct link to the video file or you make a Flash version of your media player since that can be displayed within FB posts (unless user disabled Flash plugin or is on mobile browser). Youtube and Vimeo are trusted (and liable) so they're allowed to work. You think they'll let anybody else just run some unauthorized scripts inside FB posts?

Comment: I think there is some arrangement for everyone, so I am out of the option.